# VMWare workstation 14: “not enough physical memory available to start this VM” when running VM on Ubuntu 17.10 Artful

Tags: ubuntu, memory, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I have had the issue of not being able to start my VM after I upgraded to **Ubuntu Artful (17.10)** using the VMWare Player.
My system has 16GB or RAM, 12 of those free but shortly after a boot VMWare Player is not able to start machines anymore claiming there is

```
not enough physical memory available to start this VM
```

It does not give much more information than that and directly after, the player quits itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some digging around I found this answer in the Ubuntu Forums:

> https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2373494

There is a Github user [mkubecek](https://github.com/mkubecek) who takes care of these kinds of issues and he has a patch on his page. The commit comment shows it's matching the problems:

> However, some more changes are needed (and were in fact needed even with
>   kernels older than 4.14. In particular, several users reported failures
>   when starting VMs on hosts with 4.13 kernel with message "not enough
>   physical memory" due to wrong accounting of NR_SLAB_UNRECLAIMABLE pages.

[Github Commit Link](https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules/commit/fadedd9c8a4dd23f74da2b448572df95666dfe12#diff-ae0f1d7e5facf85af1a3622655f3c70f)

Make sure to check the code if you don't want random code from forums to be running with privileges on your machine. Afterwards these are the steps to fix the issue:

```
cd /tmp
cp /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmon.tar .
tar xf vmmon.tar
rm vmmon.tar
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-
modules/fadedd9c8a4dd23f74da2b448572df95666dfe12/vmmon-
only/linux/hostif.c
mv -f hostif.c vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c 
tar cf vmmon.tar vmmon-only
rm -fr vmmon-only
sudo mv -f vmmon.tar /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmon.tar 
sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

I hope it helps others. All credits really go to izznogooood and mkubecek

Comment: You can also simply clone the repository, `git clone https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules`, checkout the branch corresponding to your product and version `git checkout workstation-14.1` and `make && sudo make install`. Don't forget to read the `README` and `INSTALL` documents in that repo as well.